# Get the filename of an image setting by ng-src

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase-storage

Is there a way to get the filename of an image that I set with `ng-src` from a url?

My image tag looks like this:

```
  <img ng-src="{{imageSrc}}" width="400" height="400" />
```

And in my controller I set the image source of a url like this:

```
      $scope.imageSrc = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/work-52105.appspot.com/o/user%2FwCBsmRGAxbMQXO2yqc8jF65pmIG3%2FDepositphotos_59984669_s-2015.jpg?alt=media&token=916f8bb6-2ccf-4a95-b76b-814db081c028";
```

When I right click on the image to save it, I can see its file name: `Depositphotos_59984669_s-2015.jpg`

Is there a way to get or extract the file name easily with JS or with Angular.js?

Thank you.

Comment: since you are setting the image, you should already have the url

Comment: I want to get its name only which is Depositphotos_59984669_s-2015.jpg and assign it to a variable for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few assumptions:

- The file name starts after a slash (either `/` or its decoded version, `%2F`)
- It ends on the first question mark.
- The image has a JPG format (although you can be easily modify it in the regex).

If all three are satisfied, you can use [this](https://regex101.com/r/fISMdw/1) regex on the URL:

```
(?:.+(?:\/|%2F))+?([^\/]+\.jpg)(?=\?)
```

Note that the [first group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/432503/3103891) contains the file's name.